# Multiple types of messaging queues in php with php-amqplib and rabbitmq

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

So, I'm trying to create a simple app that would do 4 things.

1) get a list of consumers ( if I can get those that registered .. maybe I can name them somehow when they join so it's dynamic ).

2) send a "message" to one random consumer and display the result

3) send a "message" to one specific consumer ( got from the list above or maybe a predefined list ) and display the result

4) send a "message" to all consumers and display the results as they come from each one.

The app is done in php with php-amqplib (https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) . The rabbitmq is up and running and seems to work ( tried the tutorials ).

The documentation for the amqp lib for me is a bit weird so what I'd greatly appreciate would some lines of example code and description of the params used.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what kind of help you need? You probably already have seen [examples](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/master/php-amqp) and [stubs](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/tree/master/stubs) which gives a brief idea how to communicate with RabbitMQ.

Comment: Sure, Currently I'm not sure of the amqp docs. They don't seem very friendly. I've seen the examples but they too don't actually what all the params mean. I'd need some code explaining at each of my situations

Comment: Yeah docs are damn outdated. PHP didn't removed docsfor some langs, like http://php.net/manual/pl/book.amqp.php. But from what you are asking it looks like you have to spend some time to understand how RabbitMQ (or what AMQP broker do you use). Extension is just a binding to AMQP protocol for PHP, nothing more.

Comment: Yeah .. I'm mix and matching see if I get anywhere .. thought maybe sometime will have some time to talk me through while I try to do this :) Oh well. I'll come back and post my results.

Comment: I think I've understood a lil' bit more about what's going on. http://fpaste.org/314059/35698191/ Hows does it look ?

Comment: Wait. Are you using php-amqp extension or php-amqplib library? They both provides abstraction to deal with AMQP broker, but they are separate projects.

Comment: Well, I started with the php-amqp extension ( the .so ) but gave up when I saw the docs being outdated. So I started using php-amqplib library which rabbitmq recommends in its tutorials. I know the extension is faster I'll migrate to it at a later time. I don't have many messages right now ( 5/s top ).

Comment: OK, so please edit than question to reflect with which library/extension you work (edit tags too, if you stick with the lib, replace php-amqp with php-amqplib, if you use both and question itself about both of them, just add the php-amqplib). As to the topic, I'm php-amqp contributor (pinepain on github), so if you have specific question about ext - feels free to open a chat with me or ping me in room 11 (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) to your question. And sorry about docs, I'm really overloaded and there are no free hands at this time to write proper docs/manual.

Comment: Thanks! As for the chat... I need at least a rep of 20... getting there. I think I managed to do 50% of my 2)3)and4) topics. Need to figure out a way to get the results back. And 1).

Comment: "The app is done in php with pecl-amqp ." is this still true?

Comment: As to 1) - with AMQP you can't get list of consumers, that should be done probably on app level, if you really need that. And you are not sending messages to consumers, you send messages to exchanges, then based on routing they are moved to queues and/or other exchanges (or dropped) and after that consumers may get them from queue. So from this perspective your Q is not clear a bit.

Comment: Hmm, I think I can get a list of queues and name my consumers as the queues. That would be enough for me ! I understood the part about sending messages to exchanges and then based on routing rules they get to queues from which the consumers consume them. Based on this flow there's no way to get a "result" from the consumer based on the messaged it consumed.

Comment: You can run [RPC pattern](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html) or even use [direct reply-to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) RabbitMQ feature for that to get result from consumer back to producer.

Comment: BTW, there are official RabbitMQ user group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users. You may find it useful.

Comment: Thanks ! Reading about the rpc and reply-to now ! Seems doable. And when I'm done .. there's only 1) left .. Do you think I should post the end code here for posterity ? ( maybe others in time will come and have questions or other ideas ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) can be solved by using rabbitmq's management /api/queues by naming each consumer with a persistent queue name for itself.

2,3,4, got solved like this:

```
<?php
//Producer Config
$host = "remote_host";
$port = 5672;
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$array = array("consumer1", "consumer2");
```

...

```
<?php
//Producer

if(!isset($argv[1]) || !isset($argv[2])){
        die("Specify a target and a message\n");
}

require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPSSLConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$corr_id = uniqid();

$connection = new AMQPSSLConnection($host, $port, $user, $pass, "/", array("verify_peer" => false));
$channel = $connection->channel();

$response = null;
$onResponse = function ($rep) {
        global $response;
        $response = $rep->body;
        echo " [>] Received: '".$response."'\n";
};

list($callback_queue, ,) = $channel->queue_declare("", false, false, true, false);
$channel->basic_consume($callback_queue, '', false, false, false, false, $onResponse);
$msg = new AMQPMessage($argv[2], array('correlation_id' => uniqid(), 'reply_to' => $callback_queue));

switch($argv[1]){
        case "random":
                $dest = $array[array_rand($array)];
                $type = "direct";
                break;
        case "all":
                $dest = "to_all";
                $type = "fanout";
                break;
        case $argv[1]:
                $dest = $argv[1];
                $type = "direct";
                break;
}

$channel->exchange_declare($dest, $type, false, false, false);
$channel->basic_publish($msg, $dest);
echo " [<] Sent '".$argv[2]."' to '".$dest."'\n";

try {
        if($dest == "to_all"){
                $replies = 0;
                while(!$response || $replies < count($consumers_array)){
                        $channel->wait(null, false, $timeout);
                        $replies++;
                }
        }else{
                while(!$response){
                        $channel->wait(null, false, $timeout);
                }
        }
}catch(PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException $e){
        echo " [x] AMQPTimeoutException thrown\n";
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

...

```
<?php
//Consumer config
$host = "remote_host";
$port = 5672;
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$consumer_name = "consumerX";
```

...

```
<?php
//Consumer
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPSSLConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$connection = new AMQPSSLConnection($host, $port, $user, $pass, "/", array('verify_peer' => false));
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->exchange_declare('to_all', 'fanout', false, false, false);
$channel->exchange_declare($consumer_name, 'direct', false, false, false);
$channel->queue_declare($consumer_name, false, false, true, false);
$channel->queue_bind($consumer_name, 'to_all');
$channel->queue_bind($consumer_name, $consumer_name);
echo '[*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C', "\n";

$callback = function($msg) {
        echo " [>] Received: '".$msg->body."'\n";
        $rand = rand(1,3);
        sleep($rand);
        $reply = uniqid()." - slept ".$rand;
        echo " [<] Replied: '".$reply."'\n";
        $raspuns = new AMQPMessage($reply);
        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_publish($raspuns,'',$msg->get('reply_to'));
};

$channel->basic_consume($consumer_name, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

Not sure this is the best way but it got my "hello world" going.